# Gunicorn workers with Docker Containers

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I have written a simple flask endpoint that updates a table and add a new entry to another table in PostgresRDS. My question is related to the scalability of the application. I want to know what will happen if I specify 3 Workers for gunicorn and then scale the same application to multiple containers using `docker-compose --scale` command.

Will each container spin up its own 3 different workers or every container will use the same 3 workers. This way if scale is 2 using nginx I can serve atleast 6 concurrent requests or will it still be 3 ?

Comment: How many requests can be server per gunicorn instance is determined by the workers x the number of threads and usually much higher than 6.

Comment: @KlausD. [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/0.16.1/design.html#:~:text=Generally%20we%20recommend) recommend using `(2 x $num_cores) + 1` as the default.

Comment: But my point is if a single application is replicated to 2 Containers and each container starts the application with 2 Worker and 1 Thread then will each docker container has its own workers ?

There is some concept related to containers which I am missing

Comment: @Rahul Khanna, I think you will run into ports collision when you will try to scale your docker services

Comment: @sudden_appearance that can be taken care of with Ngnix in front of containers. Point I am asking has nothing to do with Port Collision I think

Comment: Then there is going to be 2 containers with unique gunicorn instances and 3 workers for each. Docker containers are isolated from outside and don't know nothing about each other

Comment: @sudden_appearance do you have a documentation or post that verifies this thing because my assumption is also the same but I have read that containers use host machine resources. So I am not really sure